# joining multiple sql tables on basis of primary key

Tags: mysql

I have around 10 tables. One table that has primary key and all other tables are connected to that single table through foreign key.
eg.

```
Table main : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
Tablechild: 1,2,3
Tableanchild: 1,3,5
Tableachild: 1,2,4,5
```

I want to extract complete data for main table and all other tables eg.

```
1      "tablechild data" "tableanchild data" tableachild data"
2      tablechild data                       tableachild data
3      tablechild data    tableanchild data
4 
5 
6
7
8
```

I used `left join` but it is giving reduntant data. For every table displaying foreign key thank you in advance.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM login AS jon
                        LEFT JOIN re as rec ON jon.no=rec.no
                        LEFT JOIN bio as bio ON jon.no=bio.no   
                        LEFT JOIN pon as po ON jon.no=po.no
                        LEFT JOIN rec as re ON jon.no=re.no
                        LEFT JOIN spn as sp ON jon.no=sp.no" ;
```

I also tried

```
" SELECT login.no,re.name ,re.num,bio.address,bio.phone,pon.lline,pon.set,rec.book,rec.pen,spn.rub,spn.stylo FROM login,re,bio,pon,rec,spn WHERE login.no=re.no AND login.no=bio.no  AND login.no=pon.no  AND login.no=rec.no  AND login.no=spn.no ";
```

I want to do like 
SELECT A.x , B.y , B.z, C.d ,C.f FROM A,B,C  WHERE A.X is distinct
as x is primary key in A and foreign key in others .
expected output

```
1    B data
2    B data      C data
3                C data
4    B data      C data
5
```

now i am getting

```
   1   B data
   1   ....
   1   .......
   2   ....
   2   ......
   3
   4
   4
   5
```

Comment: please provide the query you used until now.

Comment: and maybe the creates of these tables?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek: I edited and provided both way that I tried.First one is giving redundant foreign key and second one is giving intersection as there may not be no for all tables

Comment: is "login" your main table? if yes then you should not see any redundant data in your first query (assuming one entry per fk in a child table as in the example you gave)

Comment: @kristof: First of all thank u very much. yes its fine and login is my main table.But wen I am running query on sql yog it is just displaying no column for every table which is primary in login and foreign in others.and wen I am exporting it to csv it is not displaying all noces .Thank you again

Comment: @kristof: I tried something else . If I am removing where clause and using select a.no,b.nm,b.nk,c.kl,c.ml..... from a,b,c  then it is giving reduntant values.I just want to use distinct on just a.no. Thank u in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

left join should work here

Here is an example (I am using sql server but the logic should be exactly the same)

```
declare @main table (pk int)

insert into @main(pk) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8)

declare @childA table(afk int)
declare @childB table(bfk int)
declare @childC table(cfk int)

insert into @childA(afk) values (1),(2),(3)
insert into @childB(bfk) values (1),(3),(5)
insert into @childC(cfk) values (1),(2),(4),(5)


select * from 
    @main m
    left join @childA a on m.pk = a.afk 
    left join @childB b on m.pk = b.bfk  
    left join @childC c on m.pk = c.cfk
```

Just make sure that the **main** is the starting table and there should be no redundant data.

So in your case your query would be something like:

```
select * from 
    mainTable m
    left join childA a on m.pk = a.afk 
    left join childB b on m.pk = b.bfk  
    left join childC c on m.pk = c.cfk
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the table `A` has cloumn `x` and `y` and B has `x` and `z`

Then query `select * from A, B where A.x = B.x` will give redundant data. As you said. 
Alternatively you can write the query as `select A.x, A.y, B.y from A, B where A.x = B.x`

Comment: I already tried both way. First one is giving redundant data and second one is giving just one row as there are many tables and some of them do not have foreign key associated to primary key and as i am using AND it is just giving intersection of all

Comment: IT is ok for two tables but i have around 10 and when I am using and A.x= B.x and A.x=C.x then it is giving intersection . while i want all A.x values